# Is there any reason to use AppCompat`?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, mobile-development

I was struggling with using `AppCompatActivity` and `Activity` (and recently realized there is `ActivityCompat` even) and things like `Toolbar` vs `ActionBar` etc. it feels like things using `AppCompat` seem to be more stable. For example it works so much more smoothly with things like `PreferenceFragment`.

On the other hand, as I understand the `AppCompat` is mostly for supporting devices below APIv21 which not even supported by security patches today.

So, is there any reason to use `AppCompat` in a new application? What is the future of `AppCompat`? Is it a sliding window of versions or `AppCompat` will be phased off in future?

Thanks!

Comment: WHile this is probably more opinion based question `AppCompat` will get regular bug fixes if it needs it and provides backwards compatability vs a normal `Activity` which really wont get any bug fixes until a new android version and if you need something specific for a newer android version you have no way to packport the usage for older devices. I would say is there a reason to NOT use it?

Comment: @tyczj: "I would say is there a reason to NOT use it?" -- 1MB of resources and ~12K method references is one reason. `AppCompatActivity` adds little to no value on its own; it is mostly there to wire in the rest of the scaffolding for the `Theme.AppCompat` support on pre-5.0 devices. `appcompat-v7` fixes ~0 bugs in the framework classes, as it does not replace the framework classes (the way, say, `support-fragment` replaces `Fragment`).

Comment: So what you are saying is that `AppCompat` support a sliding window of old versions. After 2 years we won't need to change it to something else? Meanwhile, for example 'Activity' will drop support of Android5 devices in future?

Comment: "Meanwhile, for example 'Activity' will drop support of Android5 devices in future?" -- no. `Activity` has been there since API Level 1. It will remain there for the foreseeable future, for backwards compatibility.